# Replace nested promise.all with observable stream to aggregate over an array

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

In an Angular app we have a method which merges 3 api results in a single giant list.

```js
loadPlaces$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(PlaceActionTypes.LOAD_PLACES),
    switchMap((action: LoadPlaces) =>
      from(this.service.findAreas()).pipe(
        switchMap(async (areas: Area[]) => {
          try {
            const places: Place[] =  await Promise.all(
              areas.map(async (area: Area) => {
                const [residential, commercial] = await Promise.all([
                  this.service.getResidentials(area.id),
                  this.service.getCommercial(area.id),
                ]);

                return new Place(area, residential, commercial);
              })
            );
            return new LoadPlacesSuccess(places);
          } catch (error) {
            return new LoadPlacesFail(error);
          }
        }),
        catchError((error) => of(new LoadPlacesFail(error)))
      )
    )
  );
```

We retrieve all areas. Then for each one, we must construct an object `Place` which contain information on the area + 2 other information (residential and commercial).

We end up with an array of `Place`, each containing nested data.

The fact is our methods will stop to return promise and use observable all the way.

**I cannot find a way to transform my current chain to use only observables.** I managed to get both residential and commercial at the same time using combineLatest but I become lost at the time of mapping over my areas array. Indeed I have to return a result from nested calls for each area and have no idea on how we can ask rxjs to subscribe observables along the way automatically (not having to call `.subscribe()`).

**How can I achieve this "each item" nested combineLatest subscription?**

I tried a mix of from() and switchMap() nested with combineLatest() with no success. I always ends up with an array of observables and not values.

Comment: Please give an [mcve] illustrating a specific problem with your attempt.

Comment: why are these service methods returning promises?

Comment: @bryan60 it was an old system requirement and we then moved to a new pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will look like this, it's a lot of forkJoin -> map

```
switchMap((action: LoadPlaces) =>
  from(this.service.findAreas()).pipe(
    switchMap((areas: Area[]) => {
      return forkJoin( // forkJoin 
        areas.map((area: Area) => { // map to observables 
          return forkJoin([ // forkJoin these too
            from(this.service.getResidentials(area.id)), // convert them to observables
            from(this.service.getCommercial(area.id)),
          ]).pipe( // map the result
            map(([residential, commercial]) => new Place(area, residential, commercial))
          );
        }) 
      ).pipe( // map this result too
        map(places => new LoadPlacesSuccess(places))
      );
    }),
    catchError((error) => of(new LoadPlacesFail(error)))
  )
)
```

Comment: I didn't have the idea to map over areas within forkJoin. It helps a lot! Do we have to destructure doing `...areas.map()` cause it seems I have only one call made on the first area in the first forkJoin?

Comment: Destructuring should not be needed. It’s important that everything inside forkJoin completes, so the issue may be in your service implementation.